# Insert ellipsis to the partial text inside the anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, ellipsis, elasticlayout

`<a href="#" >some lengthy text -- 07 May 2014 -- order ID#12345 </a>`

I have an anchor tag inside that I have some text,date, number(text -- date -- number format) like as shown above I want to ellipsis only the text according to the out div in such a way that whole anchor content(text,number,date) should not wrap to new line.

In the above example I want to ellipsis only text(some lengthy text) It should not disturb the number and date

I tried putting `<p>` tag around text with some CSS it is able to ellipsis properly but the issue is underline for anchor tag looks like made up of 2 piece I don't want that
http://jsfiddle.net/Vc4N6/3/

Is there a better way of doing this in javascript ? so that I don't have to struggle with CSS(with different browser IE8&9 is must along other browser. )

**NOTE: I don't use jQuery solution should be in pure javascript**

**EDIT:**

I got solution for above question but my requirement is bit more I will be using these line item in list, after adding to list it is introducing space between text and date if I have varying text in each line item.see here http://jsfiddle.net/Vc4N6/13/

Ideally It should look like

- this is very lengthy text lengthy text.. -- 07 May 2014 -- order
  ID#12345
- short text -- 06 Jun 2015 --    order
  ID#46453

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `ellipsis` by the way, not ellipse.

http://jsfiddle.net/Vc4N6/12/

```
.e {
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width:70px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space:nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer but my requirement is bit more.see the demo(http://jsfiddle.net/Vc4N6/13/) but the second row has space in between is it possible to fix this issue ?

Comment: Yes, use `max-width` instead of `width`. I updated my answer.

Comment: Could you show a minimal sample that has this working *in your post*? As it stands, your code just doesn't make sense without following external links, and that's really not a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

If I get the question right, you can do it without javascript using `display: inline-block`, `vertical-align: middle`, `white-space: nowrap` and few other css props.
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/m_ms27/Vc4N6/7)

Comment: can you please help me out some more,see updated code http://jsfiddle.net/Vc4N6/14/ can you please help me in removing extra space it is because of I have lengthy text in some line item and short text in others, after shorter text it is introducing space.

Comment: To do that, just reduce width on `.e` to the point you need. E.g. `.e { width: 50px; }`